# Undesired faint outline around div with background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am overlaying a simple `<div>` containing a single `<p>` tag on a background image. However, as seen in the attached image, there is a very faint "outline" around this div that I have not been able to remove. I have tried using the `outline-style:none;` property, but that did not change anything. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.titleText { 
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:30px;
}

* {
    background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The `.titleText` class refers to the `<p>` tag inside an otherwise empty, classless `<div>`.

How can I remove this faint outline?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
* {
    background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Instead apply background for body tag or a container div Ex.

```
body{
background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

If you apply background image for universal selector then it will be applied on every element.That's why you were getting that overlay.

Comment: Fantastic. This worked well. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.titleText { 
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:30px;
}

.background-div {
height: 400px;
background-size: cover;
    background-image:url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/23049/pexels-photo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
You have a global selector for your background image which you should not do as this will apply it to every element on your page. 

Instead, apply the bg to the containing div, then use border box model (and I recommend some sort of reset too).
```

```html
<div class="background-div">
<p class="titleText">Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help.